# undefined reference to 'SHA512@OPENSSL_0.9.8'

Tags: ssl, ld

I'm trying to link my code against a shared library ("libX.so") which depends on libcrypto.so. I have libcrypto.so.1.0.0 installed, but it seems to specifically require libcrypto.so.0.9.8. Is there a way to get it to link against 1.0.0? I can't install 0.9.8 on my system (archlinux) without breaking other packages.

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcrypto.so.0.9.8, needed by /usr/local/lib/libX.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/local/lib/libX.so: undefined reference to `SHA512@OPENSSL_0.9.8'
...
```

EDIT:

I should probably add more information. I have tried compiling openssl 0.9.8 and installing to the prefix /usr/local. But even though it seems to find this library, there are still errors when building:

```
/usr/local/lib/libX.so: undefined reference to `SHA512@OPENSSL_0.9.8'
...
```

libcrypto does seem to define this:

```
$ nm /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 | grep SHA512
000000000006f9b0 T SHA512
...
```

I am using the following script to compile:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=:/usr/local/ssl/lib
gcc -I/usr/local/include/ test.c -o test -lX
```

And this is the output of ldd on libX:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/lib/libX.so              
/usr/local/lib/libX.so: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8: no version information available (required by /usr/local/lib/libX.so)
libssl.so.0.9.8 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f9c4e329000)
libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f9c4df99000)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

refer to http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-835256-start-0.html

`openssl-0.9.8l-sym-version-felixrabe.patch` work fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

Because the original OpenSSL library was built with a version script. This is a feature so you can have different versions of the the library and still get the right symbol.

You can add your own looking like this:

```
OPENSSL_0.9.8 {
 *;
};
```

And then link with --version-script

To make OpenSSL do this you probably need to edit the Makefile.